# How to install gtkspell spell-check on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: spell-checking

What package do I need to install to meet the `gtkspell` spell-check dependency in Zim Wiki?

```
orschiro@x230:~$ dpkg -l | grep gtkspell # grep deb package
ii  libgtkspell-dev                                      2.0.16-1.1ubuntu1                                           amd64        Development files for GtkSpell
ii  libgtkspell0                                         2.0.16-1.1ubuntu1                                           amd64        a spell-checking addon for GTK's TextView widget
ii  libgtkspell3-3-0:amd64                               3.0.7-2                                                     amd64        spell-checking addon for GTK+'s TextView widget
ii  python-gtkspell                                      2.25.3-13                                                   amd64        Python bindings for the GtkSpell library
ii  python-gtkspellcheck                                 3.0-1.1                                                     all          spellchecking library written in Python for Gtk based on Enchant
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: You can get the gtkspell from here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/gtkspell

Comment: I already have these packages installed but they do not meet the dependency. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/e28GQPj.png).

Comment: `dpkg -l *gtkspell*` would have worked just as well. No need to list all packages just to `grep` them afterwards. What you actually wanted was probably `apt-cache search gtkspell`, which searches all packages is the currently configured repositories and not just all packages that have been installed on your system at some point. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`apt-cache search gtkspell` finds the package `python-gtkspellcheck` which sounds exactly like what you want.

You can also find it in the list of recommended packages of `zim`:

```
$ apt-cache show zim | grep '^Recommends:'
Recommends: python-gtkspell
```

You can display and install recommended packages through Synaptic via the context menu or through Apt (with the `--install-recommends` option in case you disabled the default `APT::Install-Recommends` configuration setting):

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends zim
```

Comment: There is no python-gtkspell, only python-gtkspellcheck; that's why gtkspell check failed

Comment: @Ludenticus: Ah, I see now. The `zim` package suggests the installation of a package `python-gtkspell` that doesn't exist in Xenial (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/zim). So that dependency is unsatisfiable with just the repositories. Zim seems to have found `gtkspellcheck` instead though. Is that enough to get spell checking to work? Considering your answer below it does, but I'd rather read your confirmation before I delete mine.

Comment: Yes, Zim needs only one package to work (either gtkspell or gtkspellcheck). I was looking for a way to install both (when I posted my comment) until I realised that this had no reason. So, your answer is formally correct. I added mine to clarify this point.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, there is no need to install *both* packages. From Zim wiki:

> Dependencies: This plugin requires either of two libraries: "gtkspell" or "gtkspellcheck", if both are installed, the later is used.

You can then select the plugin and configure the language.

[image: Zim gtkspell]

Answer (score 1):

Try [via pip](https://github.com/koehlma/pygtkspellcheck/issues/29#issuecomment-237796505), it worked for me.